# C# create restore point netframework 3.5

Tags: c#, restore-points

Is it possible to create a restore point along with all required tasks (enable system protection, resize shadowstorage) from C# in a netframework 3.5 target?

I found some examples, but they all use System.Management.Automation to execute PowerShell scripts which isn't available in netframework 3.5.
What I am trying to do is to bind the whole action (enable system restore if disabled, resize shadowstorage and create restore point) on a button inside a GUI.

Comment: You can always just run PowerShell with `Process.Run` alongside any script you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a winforms code using *WMI*, enjoy:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Security;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System.Management;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WMISample
{
    public class CallWMIMethod
    {
        public new static int Main()
        {
            try
            {
                ManagementObject classInstance = new ManagementObject(@"root\DEFAULT", "SystemRestore.ReplaceKeyPropery='ReplaceKeyPropertyValue'", null);

                // Obtain [in] parameters for the method
                ManagementBaseObject inParams = classInstance.GetMethodParameters("CreateRestorePoint");

                // Add the input parameters.

                // Execute the method and obtain the return values.
                ManagementBaseObject outParams = classInstance.InvokeMethod("CreateRestorePoint", inParams, null);

                // List outParams
                Console.WriteLine("Out parameters:");
                Console.WriteLine("ReturnValue: {0}", outParams("ReturnValue"));
            }
            catch (ManagementException err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while trying to execute the WMI method: " + err.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```